# Summation with combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have been trying to solve a problem related to a topic called random walk. I wanted to find the average position.

The equation I got is:

$$\bar x = \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}(2n-N)ap^n q^{N-n}$$

Here $p$ is the probability of going right and $(1-p)$ is the probability of going left. I'm confused how the next equation has been done, specially the summed over part.

The way author did the next line is separating the equation, specially the red part.

$$\bar x = 2ap \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n q^{N-n}  \ - \color{Red}{Na}$$

I'm adding how the author did his calculation which I did not understand the sum.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original equation, the author split the summation involving the $2n - N$ into $2$ separate summations, i.e.,

$$\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}(2n)ap^n q^{N-n} + \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}(-N)ap^n q^{N-n} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The second part which was separated, i.e., $-Na\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n q^{N-n}$, gives a result of $-Na$. In particular, it means $\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n q^{N-n} = 1$. Note the LHS is the binomial expansion of $(p+q)^N$, so if $q = 1 - p \implies p + q = 1$, you'll get $\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n q^{N-n} = (p + q)^N = 1$, so the equation will be true. Note this is also a case of the sum of all possible probabilities among $N$ occurrences adding up to $1$.

As for the second equation's first term, the summed over part, note the partial derivative with respect to $p$ only affects the $p^n$ factor. Thus, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2ap \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n q^{N-n} & = 2ap \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}(n)p^{n-1} q^{N-n} \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}(2n)ap^{n} q^{N-n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

As you can see, this is the first term in \eqref{eq1}, i.e., the original summation's expression without the $-N$ part in the brackets.

Comment: I was just about to comment this. It seems like the line is copied wrong or the book has an error.

Comment: @TheCount Thanks for letting me know you also noticed this. I originally thought there was a factor missing, but I then realized that the author had split the original summation into $2$ parts, so it seems the second part with the term $-Naq^{N}$ along with this summation gives $-Na$. I updated my answer accordingly, although I'm still not sure about how those $2$ parts add up.

Comment: I was in the midst of posting an answer when I realized it wasn't adding up, so I stopped because I thought I was just having a *moment*, as it is, but when I saw you noticed it too, I felt better. Ha.

Comment: @TheCount I just realized at $n = 0$, it doesn't take the first term of $-Naq^{N}$ as this is part of the summation split off. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually my concern was how the second part was done, since the first  part can be done by taking the derivative.

Comment: @user193422 Thanks for adding what the author did. Note I've added some more details to my answer, including that the sum part adding to $1$ is a binomial expansion of $(p+q)^N$ which would be $1$ if $q = 1 - p$, which is what I assume is the case.